# Run robot framework test without put it in the template file

Tags: python, robotframework

So I have this robot file:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    my_project/products/ese_base_template.robot

*** Test Cases ***
Test_1
    [Tags]  sanity
    foo.some_function
```

**Template file**

```
*** Settings ***
Library     my_project.src.my_manager.foo_class.Foo       WITH NAME       foo

*** Keywords ***
```

**My class**

```
class Foo:
    def some_function(self):
        print('Some function')
```

So I want to run this `.robot` test without specify the test in my template file under `*** Test Cases ***` so I just run the command `robot path_to_my_test_file.robot` anf got this error:

```
Suite 'Ese Base Template' contains no tests or tasks.
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you don't want to define any keywords?

Say, have the test case call a keyword:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    my_project/products/ese_base_template.robot

*** Test Cases ***
Test_1
    [Tags]  sanity
    Call some function
```

then have that keyword defined in the template, like:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     my_project.src.my_manager.foo_class.Foo       WITH NAME       foo

*** Keywords ***
Call some function
    foo.some_function
```

You don't need to include the test cases in the template file, and you can still run the command `robot path_to_my_test_file.robot`